# Way better to write condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to write a clean condition, a better way

```
if DateTime.now.to_date == exercicio.dta_fim - 15 || 
DateTime.now.to_date == 
exercicio.dta_fim - 10 || DateTime.now.to_date == exercicio.dta_fim - 5
```

And i want to check this conditions and when it return true, render in a partial view in other page dinamically how many days is missing, 15 or 10 or 5

Answer (score 7):

You could calculate the difference between `exercicio.dta_fim` and the current date:

```
days_missing = exercicio.dta_fim - Date.current
```

And do something if it is 5, 10, or 15:

```
if [5, 10, 15].include?(days_missing)
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be cleaner, but surely simpler.

```
[15, 10, 5].any? { |n| DateTime.now.to_date == exercicio.dta_fim - n }
```

I recommend you create a helper for this.